Upload USDZ model using AWSS3 in Vision OS
I want to upload my usdz model on s3 bucket. But giving below error while set credential.
let accessKeyId = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
        let secretAccessKey = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
        do{
            // Setup AWS credentials, connection config and client
            let credentialsProvider = try StaticCredentialsProvider(Credentials(accessKey: accessKeyId!, secret: secretAccessKey!))
            let configuration = try S3Client.S3ClientConfiguration(region: "sa-east-1", credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
            let client = S3Client(config: configuration) 
}

I am getting below errors, I am referring https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/spatial/getting-started-with-vision-pro-and-aws/


This line:
let credentialsProvider = try StaticCredentialsProvider(Credentials(accessKey: accessKeyId!, secret: secretAccessKey!))

should be this:
let credentialsProvider = try StaticCredentialsProvider(credentials(accessKey: accessKeyId!, secret: secretAccessKey!))

Note the lowercase "c" in "credentials"; The uppercase "C" might be a typo in the documentation.

There is no any typo!!

@Sam007 Did you try using a lowercase "c"?

Yes, I have tried it. but no success!!

One solution for this is that you change the version of AWS SDK for swift, such as 0.24.0 in which StaticCredentialsProvider exists.
